# Setting same width or height of views in XML

Tags: android, xml, view, size

I started to learn android and I'm making a simple game. In this game I need two scroll lists with the same width, so I set layout_weight parameter to "1" in both views. But when I run program scroll views have different size. Second problem is that i need EditText widget to be low, so I did the same thing with TableRows, but in the end I have to set weight to 0.1 to achieve needed size.

P.S. Sorry for my english if there are some mistakes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget28"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/widget29"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/widget34"
            android:layout_height="150px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffff00ff" >
        </ScrollView>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/widget35"
            android:layout_height="150px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff00ffff" >
        </ScrollView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/widget30"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/widget36"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Not editable"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, I replaced second TableRow with LinearLayout and everything started to work correctly. I don't know why but both TableRows were somehow connected and changing width of second one changed width of first one

Answer (score 0):

Your ScrollViews are on the same table row. Try changing the layout_weight to 0.5 instead. Then both of them should get half of the row.

Comment: I changed layout_weight to 0.5 but nothing's changed in interface.

Comment: Another thing is that I added focusable TextViews and set OnClickListener to them that adds one letter to EditText. When I run program and click on list positions width of EditText and width of left scrollView changes equally